# processing non-english text in python 2.7

Tags: python, twitter, unicode, encoding

I'm trying to process a text I got from Twitter streaming API, I'm getting a foreign texts and when I'm trying to save it to mysql database I keep getting the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>
```

he text I have is something like this:

```
\u0421\u043c\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0442\u0435
```

my system's encoding settings is

```
>>> print sys.stdout.encoding
cp437
```

I want to now what is the best way to process the text and save it to mysql database?

Thanks..

Comment: I assume you actually want to store the Russian string `Сморите`, not just store "anything valid", like `???????`, right?

Comment: yes exactly... not just russian string I have many other languages.. so I need to know what is the best approach to take when saving them as a valid string?

Comment: Basically, whenever you have to write data in some 8-bit character set, but you can choose the character set (it's not forced on you the console or the server or the whatever), choose UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously can't save that text as cp437, because cp437 doesn't have any character that matches U+0421, etc.

So, you will have to pick an encoding that *does* work, and use that. UTF-8 is the obvious choice.

You can set the charset of a MySQL database when you create it. Your Python script will have to set the same charset when it connects. For example, if you're using pyMySQL:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(usual=parameters, blah=blah, charset='utf8')
```

And then you can just give it `unicode` objects as-is.

If you have a pre-existing database that uses a different charset, you will have to convert it. And change any other scripts that talk to the database to also use UTF-8.

Note that some MySQL bindings (especially for other languages like PHP or perl) may not understand character sets at all. You'll have to wrap those up with code that explicitly encodes every string parameter to UTF-8 before passing it in to a SQL statement and decodes every string as UTF-8 received from a row set. (And it may also need to explicitly execute a `SET NAMES UTF-8` when first connecting, I'm not sure.)